# nginx serving other domains then my own

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have some issues with nginx passing traffic to my site for domains other than my own.

Seems like 'fb.citroen.nl' has their dns setup wrong (to my server). I want to block all traffic other than to bviaene.sanderdeclerck.be and www.bviaene.sanderdeclerck.be at nginx level to reduce server load.

After searching, I have seen it should be done in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. I thought it has been setup correctly, but still, traffic to fb.citroen.nl shows my site.

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
# bviaene

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name bviaene.sanderdeclerck.be www.bviaene.sanderdeclerck.be;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

edit: I did reload nginx with 'sudo nginx reload -s'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the opposite: With the `default_server` option you tell `nginx` to use this `server` block for everything, including the wrong domain.

Instead, you want another server block that deals with all domains you don't configure explictly. Something like this (of course you have to remove `default_server` from your own `server` block):

```
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return      444; # Will close the connection immediately. 
}
```

Alternatively, you could configure an error page or a redirect for this, but return code 444 will generate the least amount of traffic.

Comment: Indeed, that fixes the issue. Marked your answer as accepted sollution. Thanks a lot!